# How to split the result of a mysql query into multiple arrays on the basis of some grouping, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, database

I have php **API**(using PDO). I'm getting some data from client side and applying **mysql** query on it and and receiving the query results from database. Now what I want is to **split this query result into an Array of multiple arrays**(multi dimensional array).

Like Im sending the carts Item(11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19) IDs to the Database query like this:

```
"SELECT s.SparePartID, s.Name, s.VendorID, v.CompanyName 
FROM sparepart s 
INNER JOIN users v
ON v.VendorID= s.VendorID
WHERE s.SparePartID IN ('11', '12','13', '17', '18', '19')"
```

This above query result is following:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| SparePartID |   Name  | VendorID |     CompanyName     |
+=============+=========+==========+=====================+
|     11      |  Tyres  |    48    | Master Automotives  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|     12      |  Lights |    48    | Master Automotives  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|     13      |  Wheels |    48    | Master Automotives  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|     17      |  Torch  |    50    | *Repair Solutions*  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|     18      |   Lamp  |    50    | *Repair Solutions*  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+ 
|     19      | Camera  |    50    | *Repair Solutions*  |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------------------+
```

Now I want to save it the an **array of groups** on the basis of their Company Names. as there are **2 distinct Company Names** in this data, so I want to save this data in an array of 2 arrays, otherwise group count should be equal to **distinct** Company names.

So I want resluts to be **split up** Like:

```
[

"Group1": [

{
"SparePartID": "11",
"Name" : "Tyres",
"VendorID": "48",
"Company" : "Master Automotives"
},

{
"SparePartID": "12",
"Name" : "Lights",
"VendorID": "48",
"Company" : "Master Automotives"
},

{
"SparePartID": "13",
"Name" : "Wheels",
"VendorID": "50",
"Company" : "Master Automotives"
}

]


"Group2": [

{
"SparePartID": "17",
"Name" : "Torch",
"VendorID": "50",
"Company" : "*Repair Solutions*"
},

{
"SparePartID": "18",
"Name" : "Lamp",
"VendorID": "50",
"Company" : "*Repair Solutions*"
},

{
"SparePartID": "19",
"Name" : "Camera",
"VendorID": "50",
"Company" : "*Repair Solutions*"
}


]


]
```

Here is my PHP API code of **show_cart.php** which I want to modify to get the above results:

```
<?php

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/product.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$product = new Product($db);

// get posted data
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
// query products
$stmt = $product->cart($data);
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

// check if more than 0 record found
if($num>0){
    $products_arr=array();
    $products_arr["records"]=array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        $product_item=array(
            "SparePartID" => $SparePartID,
            "Name" => $Name,
            "Price" => $Price,
            "VendorID" => $VendorID,
            "Company" => $Company
        );
        array_push($products_arr["records"], $product_item);
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode($products_arr);
} else{
    // set response code - 404 Not found
    http_response_code(404);
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No Spare Parts found in shopping Cart ")
    );
}
?>
```

where **product.php** code is:

```
function cart($ids){
     $ids_arr = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';

     $query = "SELECT s.SparePartID, s.Name, s.VendorID, v.CompanyName FROM sparepart s INNER JOIN users v ON v.VendorID= s.VendorID WHERE s.SparePartID IN ({$ids_arr})";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute($ids);

    // return values from database
    return $stmt;
}
```

Now **Please anyone help me** to suggest **how to split the results based on Company Name**? Should I modify the query ir modify the resultant array after executing query? Please **HELP**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
array_push($products_arr["records"], $product_item);
```

To this:

```
$products_arr["records"][$product_item["Company"]][] = $product_item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT s.SparePartID, s.Name, s.VendorID, v.CompanyName FROM sparepart s 
INNER JOIN users v ON v.VendorID= s.VendorID WHERE s.SparePartID IN 
({$ids_arr}) **GROUP BY v.CompanyName**
```

Comment: That will result one row for each company name, not the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Paul Robert for ur response but actually this will result in only one row of data for each company name. My problem is solved by the very first answer.